# How to conjure Input mask Editor?

Tags: delphi

Is is possible somehow to pop up Input Mask Editor at run-time? I was looking for it on internet, but no success,  it si not included in standard dialogs...

I want user to make his own input mask...

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new form with your mask editor and pop it up.